# Assign file name to a variable using pathname expansion

Tags: bash, shell-script, dash

Is there a reliable way to assign a file name to a variable taking advantage of pathname expansion?

This works but looks kind of dodgy:

```
the_file="$(echo ~/downloads/stack-*-linux-x86_64-static.tar.gz)"
```

If the file exists its full path gets assigned to `$the_file`, otherwise a bogus glob pattern takes the place.

Comment: Are you assuming that exactly one (or at most one) file matches the pattern?

Comment: @G-Man For what I had in mind, yes (somewhat hastily written personal script). In general, I agree it's an important issue to consider whether the glob picks up two or more files in the process

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Globbing only occurs in list contexts, so you'd need to assign to an *array* variable. With `ksh93`, `bash`, `zsh`, `mksh` or `yash`:

```
the_files=(~/downloads/stack-*-linux-x86_64-static.tar.gz)
```

Or in `sh`:

```
set -- ~/downloads/stack-*-linux-x86_64-static.tar.gz
```

to assign to `$1`, `$2`...

And to get the first element: `"${the_files[1]}"` in `zsh` or `yash` (or just `$the_files[1]` in `zsh`) or `"${the_files[0]}"` in `ksh` or `bash`.

For all the elements: `"${the_files[@]}"` (also `$the_files` in `zsh`).

For the concatenation of the elements joined with the first character of `$IFS`: `"${the_files[*]}"` (also `"$the_files"` with `zsh`). Or joined with any string in `zsh`: `${(j:, :)the_files}` (here joined with `,`).

### A few more notes

#### Assignment to scalar variables

```
the_file=~/downloads/stack-*-linux-x86_64-static.tar.gz
```

The `~` would be expanded, but **not** the glob. However, if you forgot to use quotes upon expanding the variable like in:

```
printf '%s\n' $the_file # instead of printf '%s\n' "$the_file"
```

Then the content of `$the_file` would be subject to split+glob and expanded *at that point* which could make you think that it works while in fact it doesn't and here combined with tilde expansion it can even get messier.

For instance if your `$HOME` is `/All * Users/me` and `$IFS` is set to it's default value, then `$the_file` will contain `/All * Users/me/downloads/stack-*-linux-x86_64-static.tar.gz` and `printf` would print `/All` followed by all the file names in the current directory (the expansion of `*`), followed by the expansion of `Users/me/downloads/stack-*-linux-x86_64-static.tar.gz`.

#### What if the pattern doesn't match any file

In `zsh`, you'd get an error, but in other shells, the pattern is left untouched. Best here would be for the pattern to expand to nothing at all.

With `zsh`, that's with the `N` glob qualifier:

```
the_files=(~/downloads/stack-*-linux-x86_64-static.tar.gz(N))
```

`ksh93` has a similar feature with its `~(N)` glob operator:

```
the_files=(~/downloads/~(N)stack-*-linux-x86_64-static.tar.gz)
```

For other shells, you need to turn some global option on (`shopt -s nullglob` in `bash`, `set -o nullglob` in `yash`).

Comment: Had no idea about `set --`! Thanks.
Yes, word splitting is another layer of dangerous. Originally I was thinking about the `sh` case. With `bash` arrays the problem gets somewhat more manageable.